# How to convert PDF to PS using Java?

Tags: java, solaris

Currently, Adobe doesn't offer PostScript drivers for `Solaris OS`. I need to print a PDF file using Java Program. I use the `PDFBox 1.8.0`. I think if I convert PDF to PS using java, I can print the file without any problem. Any of you know, How to convert PDF to PS using Java?

Comment: I don't know how to do this with Java, but for pdf -> PS conversion I use ghostscript's   pdf2ps   utility. When I jfgi for "java library to convert pdf to postscript" the first two hits look pretty useful:

http://www.ghost4j.org/highlevelapisamples.html and 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000761.html